# go: cannot find GOROOT directory error on installing go in wsl

Tags: command-line, permissions, golang

I've installed go v1.14.2 in my root, gave it permission and then moved the go folder to another drive

```
/mnt/d/go
```

Now in the .profile and .bashrc file I've already exported the GOROOT as well as GOPATH and it looks like this.

```
export GOROOT=$mnt/d/go
export GOPATH=$mnt/d/go_space
export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/d/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

On running go version, I'm getting

```
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /d/go
```

Comment: On a side note, [you should only use `~/.profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47236669) and you should delete these lines from `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
export GOROOT=/mnt/d/go
export GOPATH=/mnt/d/go_space
export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/d/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Because `mnt` is not set as anything, `$mnt` will return nothing.

Log out and log back in to apply the changes.

---

You see, `PATH` is an [environment variable](https://linuxhint.com/bash-environment-variables/) which is already set. You can run the following command to show what it is set to:

```
echo $PATH
```

There are also other variables, like `HOME` and `USER` too:

```
echo $HOME
echo $USER
```

and you can set your own:

```
export foo=bar
```

and check it:

```
echo $foo
```

and you can also add something like `hello` to `foo` like this:

```
export foo=hello:$foo
echo $foo
```

or

```
export foo=$foo:hello
echo $foo
```

Comment: Thanx, it has solved the problem. The thing is I installed ubuntu for the first time today so don't know much about it. I'll start learning ubuntu today.